# I am getting "Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\accc\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error whenever I'm creating a new project. I could be able to create a new project by changing the gradle version, but it works only once. I have to change the gradle version every time I'm creating a project. I've tried deleting the cache folder too but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is your antivirus messing with it?

Comment: I don't see any antivirus related messages there. I'm running the default Microsoft defender

Comment: It's quite often that, your antivirus seems to kick out files which it thinks as a virus which is not a virus actually

Comment: is there anything i can do with that??